# Group-by and data get

Tags: clojure

I think I am misunderstanding GET in clojure - I am trying to mould 1 data set from another, from the below A to B.

A
ID  REGION  MIN
10346   GLBL    106
10346   ASPAC   106
10346   NA  106
10346   LATAM   106
10346   EMEA    106
10347   GLBL    32
10347   ASPAC   32
10347   NA  32
10347   LATAM   32
10347   EMEA    32
10349   NA  10
10327   NA
10344   EMEA    8
10342   ASPAC   292
10342   EMEA    292
10348   ASPAC   15
10422   EMEA    37
10438   NA  0

B
ID  EMEA    NA  ASPAC   GLBL    LATAM
10346   106 106 106 106 106 
10347   32  32  32  32  32
10349   0   10  0   0   0
10327   0   0   0   0   0
10344   8   0   0   0   0
10342   292 0   292 0   0
10348   0   0   15  0   0
10422   37  0   0   0   0
10438   0   0   0   0   0

The group by is working but I am getting null values for all the regions, I though filtering on the region I could use get to obtain that value for MIN in that record and map it to the new region field - any advise on what I am doing wrong here? Or what I should be using instead of GET?

```
(defn- create-summary [data]
(->> data

     (group-by :ID
     vals
     (map 
        (fn [recs]
            (let [a (fn [priority](get :MIN (filter #(= priority (:REGION %)) recs)))]
                {:ID (:ID (first recs))
                 :EMEA (a "EMEA")
                 :NA (a "NA")
                 :GLBL (a "GLBL") 
                 :LATAM (a "LATAM")
                 :ASPAC (a "ASPAC")
                 })))

    ))
```

Comment: Could you share the value of `data` (the fn argument) with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
(let [a (fn [priority](get :MIN (filter #(= priority (:REGION %)) recs)))]
```

Should be

```
(let [a (fn [priority](get (first (filter #(= priority (:REGION %)) recs)) :MIN))]
```